# trigger.io - Looking for data storage possibility

Tags: trigger.io

I know this is not a technical question but I don't know where to ask elsewhere.

I use the very cool toolkit called trigger.io to develop apps for both android and ios. Now I would like to use something like a database to display data in my app.

Firstly I found a realtime backend called firebase: http://www.firebase.com/
Nice but it takes a while until one gets access to it since it is still in beta.

Then I found a cloud service called Kinvey: http://www.kinvey.com/ Also interesting, but it is free as long as only 200 users download the app.

So do you know any alternatives to store data and use it for my app?

That would be very helpful,

thanks enne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) is an easy option.  Basic plan to get start is $0 a month.

Also, there is nothing stopping you from bundling (or download and saving and caching) a json file for use in your trigger.io app.

Comment: Very cool, I'll have a look at Parse. Thanks Kris. One more question: What exactly do you mean by bundling a json file? I mean, where should I store the data? Or do I misunderstand you now?

Comment: @enne87 using trigger.io you can "pull down" a remote json file... store it locally on the device... then access it later.

Comment: Aaha, I see, thanks again Kris.